# how to inject a service on basis of condition in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

There is two services in my angular app first service is for testing Demo API and second is for Live API. I want to inject those service on condition basis, how can I inject those service on condition basis.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find $Injector doc here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl', function($injector){
 var myService;
   if(...){
     myService = $injector.get('myService');
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want use only one DI in project, try to use some wrapper service, like

```
app.factory('wrapperService', function($injector) {
  if (isProduction) {
    return $injector.get('liveService');
  } else {
    return $injector.get('demoService');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the $injector service to achieve this, so if you are in a controller you could inject $injector in and so something like:

```
var myService;

if(condition) {
    myService = $injector.get('demoService');
} else {
    myService = $injector.get('liveService');
}
```